# VBA - Apply AutoFilter to All Sheet But with different criteria’s

Tags: excel

I need  to apply a AutoFilter to all columns in the sheet, but with different criteria's. 
The 1st  criteria which needs to apply to column C is to remove all future dates based on the date of previous working day ( Monday - Friday ) and to include blanks as well. 
The 2nd criteria is to remove all "Shipped" in column D.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this though?  Exactly which part is giving you problems?

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, you could solve this issue.

You need a code block to apply the Auto Filter. By simply using the syntax below, where Field is the column in a table.

```
Expression. AutoFilter( _Field_ , _Criteria1_ , _Operator_ , _Criteria2_ , _VisibleDropDown_ )
```

Field would be a number from 1 to n, representing the column number.
Define a criteria to suit your needs, and repeat for all desired columns:

```
Expression.AutoFilter(Field:=1 , "motor" , _Operator:= xlFilterValues  )

Expression.AutoFilter(Field:=2 , "radiator" , _Operator:= xlFilterValues  )
```

The example above is a sample code on how to apply 2 different criteria to 2 different columns(field 1 and 2).